# What's the difference between `cocos run` and an XCode build?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm using Cocos2d-x v3.9 and I'm seeing certain behaviour in the iOS Simulator which only appears when I execute the command `cocos run -p mac`. If I build the project through XCode I don't see the same behaviour. What are the differences between the way Cocos and XCode build a project that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen in cocos2d-js, when we do cocos run -p mac or cocos run -p ios , it actually compiles the .js files to .jsc. At runtime, the .jsc files are directly used. However, in case of xcode build, the .js files are added as resources. At runtime they are compiled by jscontext and used. Hence the latter approach will be slightly slower.